# Official record of cancelled flight - European Union

Tags: air-travel, airlines, cancellations

My flight was cancelled 3 weeks ago (London to Brussels) and as part of the refund process I need to prove it was actually cancelled.

Is there any official website with the records that I can use to prove the flight was actually cancelled?

Comment: Did you get an email or other notification that your flight was cancelled? Surely that should be sufficient.

Comment: I didn't get anything beyond the confirmation of the booking. It was a travel agency (Kiwi.com, which I suggest to avoid at all costs).

Comment: Did you have access to the "manage my booking section" of the airline's website using the PNR? Does it show the flight status? Does the airline's website allow you to look up the flight status that far back? How did you find out the flight was cancelled? Last resort: flightradar24, flightware, flightstats, airportia.... You usually need a paying subscription to go that far back, but there are free trial periods. You may also check flight status info on the departure or destination airport (though they rarely allow you to go that far back, if at all)

Comment: If they didn't email you, how do you even know it was cancelled??

Comment: @Aganju I checked it myself.

Comment: @jcaron The flight was cancelled even before I checked in. I have resorted to airportia but it is hard to believe there isnt a single database from Eurocontrol or the airports...

Comment: Apparently when you query the airline's website about the flight, the screen displays text indicating the flight was cancelled. Take a screenshot of the screen. Use the screenshot as evidence of the flight cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the airline and the airport, apparently there is no official record published regularly. However, a referral to any of the unofficial websites would do.